# MRTK - Maximum number of 64 colliders found in PokePointer overlap query

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am trying to build a color selection list in my personal project, with 48 * `PressableButtonHoloLens2` + `GridObjectCollection`. When I run and hover with the simulated fingertip, the editor gives me these warning messages.

**Q1**: Is this because too many buttons are too close to each other? Or just the number of the buttons with collider is over 64? The message says 'Consider increasing the query buffer size in the pointer profile'

**Q2**: Where can I increase the buffer size? I don't see any 'Buffer size' field in the pointer profile.

**Q3**: Would it decrease performance? (increasing the buffer size)

### Warning message

> Maximum number of 64 colliders found in PokePointer overlap query.
>   Consider increasing the query buffer size in the pointer profile.
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
>   Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.PokePointer:FindClosestTouchableForLayerMask(LayerMask,
>   BaseNearInteractionTouchable&, Single&, Vector3&) (at
>   Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.SDK/Features/UX/Scripts/Pointers/PokePointer.cs:169)
>   Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.PokePointer:OnPreSceneQuery() (at
>   Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.SDK/Features/UX/Scripts/Pointers/PokePointer.cs:127)
>   Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.FocusProvider:UpdatePointer(PointerData)
>   (at
>   Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.Services/InputSystem/FocusProvider.cs:878)
>   Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.FocusProvider:UpdatePointers()
>   (at
>   Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.Services/InputSystem/FocusProvider.cs:841)
>   Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.FocusProvider:Update() (at
>   Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.Services/InputSystem/FocusProvider.cs:518)
>   Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.<>c:b__60_0(IMixedRealityService)
>   (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:880)
>   Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:ExecuteOnAllServices(IEnumerable`1,
>   Action`1) (at
>   Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:969)
>   Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:ExecuteOnAllServicesInOrder(Action`1)
>   (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:950)
>   Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:UpdateAllServices()
>   (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:880)
>   Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:Update() (at
>   Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:580)

### To reproduce

1. Create an empty game object
2. Put 48 x PressableButtonHoloLens2 prefabs under it
3. Assign GridObjectCollection to the parent
4. Update layout (cell width x height = 0.032)
5. Run and hover with simulated hand.

### Expected behavior

No warning messages

### Your Setup (please complete the following information)

- Unity Version [e.g. 2018.4.6f1]
- MRTK Version [e.g. v2.0.0]

https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/6052

Comment: Why are you asking this here if you already created a bug report on the actual support side? I'ld expect the makers of an asset can help you way better then a community of random programmers ;) In general it seems there is a too big range for the interaction somewhere (probably some of the "react to pointer near" settings) you could try and reduce the `PointerExtend`

Answer (score 2):

> Q1: Is this because too many buttons are too close to each other? Or just the number of the buttons with collider is over 64? The message says 'Consider increasing the query buffer size in the pointer profile'

It is because there are too many buttons close to each other.

> Q2: Where can I increase the buffer size? I don't see any 'Buffer size' field in the pointer profile.

You can do this in the PokePointer prefab, in the PokePointer script, look for "Scene Query Buffer Size" field.

[image]

> Q3: Would it decrease performance? (increasing the buffer size)

Yes I anticipate it would, though unclear how much relative to other components in the scene. Note that the poke pointer does run queries every frame, at least one per hand.