# How do I modify the GrabPointer prefab to allow for more than the default 64 colliders in a scene?

Tags: mrtk

I have a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074113/mrtk-maximum-number-of-64-colliders-found-in-pokepointer-overlap-query), however for SpherePointer.

Using MRTK 2.2 as acquired by NuGet for Unity, I'm getting this warning pretty much every frame:

```
Maximum number of 64 colliders found in SpherePointer overlap query. Consider increasing the query buffer size in the pointer profile.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.SpherePointerQueryInfo:TryUpdateQueryBufferForLayerMask(LayerMask, Vector3, QueryTriggerInteraction)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.SpherePointer:OnPreSceneQuery()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.FocusProvider:UpdatePointer(PointerData)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.FocusProvider:UpdatePointers()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.FocusProvider:Update()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.<>c:<UpdateAllServices>b__63_0(IMixedRealityService)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:ExecuteOnAllServices(IEnumerable`1, Action`1)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:ExecuteOnAllServicesInOrder(Action`1)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:UpdateAllServices()
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:Update()
```

I was able to successfully remove the similar warning for PokePointer using [@Julia's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/809040/julia-schwarz) response but I'm stumped as to how to do it for the GrabPointer prefab.

This prefab has a SpherePointer script attached but the SceneQueryBufferSize property isn't exposed in the inspector because SpherePointer's custom inspector (ShperePointerInspector.cs) doesn't expose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question! It looks like you've actually found a bug. Please use the following code to work around this for now, we will post a fix shortly. The issue to track this is here: [issue 6878](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/6878)

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License. See LICENSE in the project root for license information.

using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.Editor;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using UnityEditor;

namespace Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input
{
    [CustomEditor(typeof(SpherePointer))]
    public class SpherePointerInspector : BaseControllerPointerInspector
    {
        private SerializedProperty sphereCastRadius;
        private SerializedProperty nearObjectMargin;
        private SerializedProperty grabLayerMasks;
        private SerializedProperty triggerInteraction;
        private SerializedProperty sceneQueryBufferSize;

        private bool spherePointerFoldout = true;

        protected override void OnEnable()
        {
            base.OnEnable();

            sphereCastRadius = serializedObject.FindProperty("sphereCastRadius");
            sceneQueryBufferSize = serializedObject.FindProperty("sceneQueryBufferSize");
            nearObjectMargin = serializedObject.FindProperty("nearObjectMargin");
            grabLayerMasks = serializedObject.FindProperty("grabLayerMasks");
            triggerInteraction = serializedObject.FindProperty("triggerInteraction");
        }

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            base.OnInspectorGUI();

            serializedObject.Update();

            spherePointerFoldout = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(spherePointerFoldout, "Sphere Pointer Settings", true);

            if (spherePointerFoldout)
            {
                using (new EditorGUI.IndentLevelScope())
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(sphereCastRadius);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(sceneQueryBufferSize);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(nearObjectMargin);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(triggerInteraction);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(grabLayerMasks, true);
                }
            }

            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Julia,

Since I can't modify SpherePointerInspector.cs in my project as the MRTK is obtained from NuGet and has no actual .cs files to edit. Here's the solution I came up with as a temporary workaround until MRTK 2.3 is released.

I replaced SpherePointer.cs with MySpherePointer.cs on a copy of the GrabPointer.prefab.

**MySpherePointer.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;

/// <summary>
/// This class exists soley to expose SpherePointer.queryBufferPointerSize which is
/// masked by the default SpherePointerInspector.
/// </summary>
public class MySpherePointer : SpherePointer
{
}
```

**MySpherePointerInspector.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using UnityEditor;

/// <summary>
/// This class exists soley to expose SpherePointer.queryBufferPointerSize which is
/// masked by the default SpherePointerInspector.
/// </summary>
[CustomEditor(typeof(MySpherePointer))]
public class MySpherePointerInspector : SpherePointerInspector
{
    private SerializedProperty sceneQueryBufferSize;
    private bool hiddenSpherePointerFoldout = true;
    protected override void OnEnable()
    {
        base.OnEnable();
        sceneQueryBufferSize = serializedObject.FindProperty("sceneQueryBufferSize");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
        hiddenSpherePointerFoldout = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(hiddenSpherePointerFoldout, "Hidden Sphere Pointer Settings", true);

        if (hiddenSpherePointerFoldout)
        {
            using (new EditorGUI.IndentLevelScope())
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(sceneQueryBufferSize);
            }
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```